# Lock application while factory reset Programmatically

Tags: android, reset

I'm developing an application which runs in stealth mode and I Don't want it t get uninstalled when the user applies factory reset to his cell phone. Is there any way to lock the application so that it may not get uninstalled during factory reset?

Answer (score 0):

Build your own custom ROM. Pre-install your app on that custom ROM. Anyone who factory-resets their device that is running this ROM will get the app back, though probably not its data.

Beyond that, there should be no way to survive a factory reset, outside of security flaws.